# React - recomputing values in children components

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have a react hierarchy like

```
Parent
  |- Child1
  |- Child2
```

And each children needs the same value `x`.  But suppose `x` is derived from some data from some complex computation `x = compute_my_value(data)`.  It seems there are two choices

```
// OPTION 1
function Child1(props){
   let x = compute_my_value(props.data)
   ... do something with x
}

function Child2(props){
  let x = compute_my_value(props.data)
  ... do something different with x
}
```

or

```
//Option 2
function Parent(props){
  let x = compute_my_value
  return (
    <Child1 x=x />
    <Child2 x=x />
)}
```

Option 1 lets me keep my components self-contained but doubles the compute needed.  Option 2 means the children are strongly coupled to the parent because they require `x` to be precomputed and passed in but it saves on compute (especially when there are many such children of computing `x` is expensive).

My question is this:

> Is there are 3rd option in which the children are decoupled from the
>   parents but the value of `x` can still be shared among the children?

Comment: Does `data` has a unique identifier property ? I was think using a `Map` where the key would be `data.id` and the value would be `x`

Comment: This is hard to answer with an abstract example like that. How is the Component `Child1` different from `Child2`? Do they render something significantly different? Often you want to have stateful logic in the Parent and pure rendering logic in the children. Also the new hooks are a good way to encapsulate logic and separate concerns.

Comment: What they render is similar but I made it abstract to get at the question which is whether or not there is a standard way to handle this use case in react.

Comment: The standard way is what you presented as "Option 2" I would say. And I don't see a problem with it. The purpose of your Child components is to render x and not some raw value that has to be converted to x. To extract the conversion does actually improve the reusability of the child component as they now could be used in a different case that requires another way of conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) which is normally coupled with redux, but can be used outside of it.

Basically, this library prevent computing derivable data multiple times when the original data hasn't changed which is actually what you need.

you could create a selector (called `xSelector`) like this

```
// selectors.js
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

export const xSelector = createSelector(
    data => data,
    data => compute_my_value(data)
);
```

The default cache size is 1, so it will only call `compute_my_value` when data has changed

Then you can use this selector in your `Child` components

```
import {xSelector} from "./selectors";

function Child1(props){
  const x = xSelector(props.data)
   ... do something with x
}
```